# How to disable taskbar item jump list in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

How to disable taskbar item jump list, that pops up when dragging taskbar item towards the desktop?

Comment: Can you tell us why you'd want to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I even understand your question, let alone try to answer it. Can you provide more details about what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The point is that it is also opened on the **left** click, when you move the mouse up without releasing the button. And that sometimes happens, when I want just to switch to another task but do inaccurate click. 
I never use that menu for anything, so I want to disable it for more robust task switching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) can do that.

Comment: Specifically, drag_towards_desktop (in 7+ Taskbar Tweaker's Advanced Options list) needs to be set to 1 to disable the jump list.

Answer (score 2):

This will allow you to disable the taskbar context menus for all users on the computer in Windows 7. These context menus are enabled by default in Windows 7.

1. Save this inside a file named `taskbar_context_menus_disabled.reg`.

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
   "NoTrayContextMenu"=dword:00000001
   ```
2. Right click on the .reg file and click on Merge.
3. Click on *Run*, *Yes*, *Yes*, and *OK* when prompted.

**Note:** If not needed anymore, you can delete the file.

Comment: This does not disable the content menu of items in the task bar but just on an empty spot in the task bar. It certainly doesn't do anything for all users on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to increase drag'n'drop rectangle size (that is used to detect the start of a drag operation) but can't get the satisfying solution. Too large size makes drag'n'drop annoying itself, while *a bit* larger size is not enough to solve the problem. So, still searching for the solution.

In a case anybody wants to try tweaking drag'n'drop here is how to do it:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\DragHeight
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\DragWidth

Default value is 4. 
You need to log off to apply the changes.

Answer (score -2):

go to Control Panel change the category to small icons  and then choose Taskbar And Start Menu.Then check Auto-Hide the taskbar

Comment: This hides the taskbar, but not the context menu.